# question on past or present in indirect speech

Tags: indirect-speech

Amit: I will send you an email.
Me: OK.

After one day how can i tell this indirectly. Should i say Amit told me that he would send me an email or Amit told me that he will send me an email.

It is now past because he didn't send me an email
It is also possible he can still send me an email

I am confused should i use will or would?

Comment: If you're still expecting Amit to send you an email (that is, you're anticipating the email will come yet), you can say "*will"*.  If you've pretty much lost hope, or simply want to describe your exchange with Amit, you'd say "would". In other words: if your boss is asking you about that questions he had, and want to pass the buck (I.e. blame) Amit, say "would" (because it means he *hasn't* and implies he *won't*).